# When user clicks a button weird text appears in inputbox

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my xml code for a sample button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.166"     
    android:text="1"
    android:onClick="ProcessInput" />
```

Now in mainActivity.java i wrote this code

```
public void ProcessInput(View v)
{
    Button btn = (Button) v;
    inputText.append(btn.toString());
}
```

The output is shown in the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply convert to string not getting value of button so change from

```
inputText.append(btn.toString());
```

to

```
inputText.append(btn.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.getText()` to get button text. `btn.toString()` will return id of `btn`.

Try this

```
inputText.append(btn.getText().toString());
```